# Values printed are different when debugging

Tags: python

```
cnt = 0
s = 'aghe'
s_len = len(s)
s_len = s_len - 1
while s_len >= 0:
    if s[s_len] in ('aeiou'):
        cnt += 1
    s_len -= 1
    break;
print ('numofVowels:'),cnt
```

This does print the value of `cnt`. When debugging, `cnt` has the correct value!

Comment: Get rid of the `;` after `break;` for one thing. What is the problem you want help with?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Python 2 or 3? Does print, or does not print?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get rid of the `break`, and make sure to include `cnt` inside the parentheses for your `print` call (having it outside the parentheses will cause it not to print in Python 3):

```
cnt = 0
s = 'aghe'
s_len = len(s)
s_len = s_len - 1

while s_len >= 0:
    if s[s_len] in ('aeiou'):
        cnt += 1
    s_len -= 1
print('numofVowels:', cnt)
```

The `break` in your while loop will ensure that it only loops once, and then stops (`break`s), which is probably not what you want if you are trying to count all the vowels in a string. Also, if you must use `break` don't follow it with a semicolon `;`. This will not cause a syntax error in Python, but is not necessary in this case, and is used exclusively (AFAIK) for putting multiple statements on a single line in Python (e.g., `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`), and even that usage is generally discouraged.